# Want to check the cell by cell value of dataframe is null or not if found null then it should fill with 0 using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I just wanted to check the cell by cell value of the dataframe is null or nan if found nan then it should be fill with zero using pandas .I have one csv file which contains the some NAN values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("samp.csv")
print(df)
for rowindex, row in df.iterrows():
    for colind , value in row.items():
       print(value)

       if value.isnull():
```

Comment: `df=df.fillna(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a dedicated command for that: `df.fillna(0)`.

The full code would then be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("samp.csv")
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with fillna() function in pandas dataframe

```
df.fillna(0)
```

For more details :- [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-nan-values-with-zeros-in-pandas-dataframe/]